# Delphi 10.1 Berlin: SOAP Abstract Error

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've migrated an ISAPI DLL SOAP from Delphi 10 Seattle to Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2.

After migration a runtime "Abstract Exception" is raised.

I notice that the class "TWebRequest" in "Web.HTTPApp.pas" requires

```
// Read count bytes from client
function ReadClient(var Buffer: TBytes; Offset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload; virtual; abstract;
function ReadClient(var Buffer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload; virtual; abstract;
```

But the "TISAPIRequest" in "Web.Win.IsapiHTTP" does not implement the first function.

So in "Web.Win.IsapiHTTP", I've copied 3 params ReadClient from 2 param function:

```
function TISAPIRequest.ReadClient(var Buffer: TBytes; Offset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Count;
  if not ECB.ReadClient(ECB.ConnID, @Buffer, DWORD(Result)) then
    Result := -1;
end;
```

"Abstract Error" exception disappear but "Stream read error" is raised.

Have you found a similar issue?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I think this is the workaround: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14919

Comment: Your workaround seems to work. If you want it can be proposed as solution for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another Delphi bug.

Solution can be found at [this address](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14919)

Simply replace 3 bugged functions with the correct ones.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I decided not to publish it as an answer because moderators here are just waiting to down vote these kinds of answers. They usually don't have anything else to do. LOL